# Hadoop - requestion for network lan password during starting cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I can't understant what password is expected by hadoop.
I configured it according to tutorial. I do:

```
sudo su
#bash start-dfs.sh
```

And now it expects someting like password lan's network. I have no idea what should I write.
As you can see, I run script as root. Of course master (from that I run script) may ssh to slaves as root without password (I configured and tested it).

Disclaimer: It is possbile that I give incorrect name (for example for script name - it is beacause of I don't understand exactly now. However I am sure that it was about something like `lan's network password`)

Help me please, for which a password is it?

**Edit**: I was using http://backtobazics.com/big-data/setup-multi-node-hadoop-2-6-0-cluster-with-yarn/

Comment: Can you update your post with which tutorial you followed to configure

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may not setup passwordless-ssh. Passwordless-ssh is required to run hadoop services (daemons). So try to setup ssh among nodes

`$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa`

`$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

`$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Then `ssh user@hostname`

Comment: I wrote that I configured it and tested it.